# Python/Kivy - Button font_size doesnt change

Tags: python, button, kivy, font-size

i have a little problem :

when i create a button or a label in `.kv file` :

```
<ResultScreen>:
    container: container

    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Button:
            id: parent3
            text: "Tarifs"
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint: .7, .1
            background_normal: ''
            background_down: ''
            background_color: .88,.88,.88, 1
            font_size: container.width/15

        ScrollView:

            bar_width: 10
            bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
            bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
            scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']

            StackLayout:
                id: container
                size_hint_y: None
                
                Label/Button:
                    bold: True
                    text: "Département :"
                    font_size: container.width/18 # <-- This button works well
```

The font_size will perfectly match my window width and 'update' dynamicly when i change my window size.

BUT

when i create a Label/Button (in the same parent than before) via some code in the `.py file` the font_size doesnt change when i change my window size.

Widget created in the .py file cant update dynamicly while the app is running ?
Thanks.

EDIT : (This is how my buttons are created via my `.py file`)

```
class ResultScreen(Screen):
    container = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ResultScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup_scrollview, 1)

    def setup_scrollview(self, dt):
        self.container.bind(minimum_height=self.container.setter('height'))

    def afficher_tarifs(self):
        for i in range(len(tarif_final_ini)):
            self.btn_tarif = Button(text="Formule " + str(i + 1) + " : " + str(round(tarif_final_ini[i], 2)) + " €",
                                        size_hint_y=None, height=40, disabled=True, bold=True,
                                    background_disabled_normal='', background_color=(0, 0, 0, 1), disabled_color=(0.87, 0.16, 0.1, 1), font_size= parent1.width/18)
            self.container.add_widget(self.btn_tarif, index=i)
```

Buttons are in a StackLayout with ScrollView. I tried to create Buttons in the same StackLayout via `.kv file`, the font_size 'update' properly.
So the problem is not the StackLayout or the ScrollView (i guess).

The font_size seems to 'update' only when i change Screen and come back to this Screen.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Post edited with more informations, thanks.